# как отправить заголовок при запросе ресурса тегом <audio src="url"/>?

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

GET запрос на сервере требует аутентификации при помощи передачи токена в заголовке,
но как передать заголовок в запросе, который отправляет браузер для тега  ?

прочитал, что у тега аудио есть аттрибут crossorigin, с помощью которого можно использовать стандартные методы http аунтефикации, но как установить заголовок непонятно

```
<audio src="url" crossorigin="use-credentials" />
```

подскажите как установить заголовок Authorization для такого запроса?

```
import React from "react";
import {SERVER} from '../constants';

export const Player = ({recordingId}) => {

let jwt = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('auth')).jwt;
if (typeof jwt !== "string") return false;

return <audio
    src={SERVER + '/records/' + recordingId}
    controls
    crossOrigin="use-credentials"
  />
}
```

Comment: Совсем не понятно, что автор пытается реализовать... При чем тут `GET-запрос`, что именно надо отправить на сервер?

Comment: пытаюсь загрузить mp3 файл с сервера и отобразить его в <audio />

Comment: браузер сам отправляет GET когда рендерится тег <audio />

Comment: ну а где код? .... покажи код, как и что ты пытаешься реализовать...

Comment: компонент реакта Player подгружает по клику mp3 файл и проигрывает

Comment: собственно все загвоздка в теге audio, остальной код работает отлично)

Comment: нужно передать jwt в заголовке Authorization, чтобы сервер вернул файл, иначе ответ 401

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле в вашем случае несколько вариантов.

**1**. Давать клиенту подписанную ссылку на аудио дорожку, к примеру:

```
 <audio src="audio.mp3?exp=unix_ts&sign=<sign>" crossorigin="use-credentials"/>
```

Где `sign` - это `SHA256(exp, sailt)`
При запросе на сервер будет необходимо сравнить подпись, и проверить время жизни ссылки.

**2**. Передавать токен авторизации в query параметре, и на сервере извлекать его от туда.

```
<audio src="audio.mp3?authorization=<Bearer token>" crossorigin="use-credentials"/>
```

**3**. Воспользоваться fetch api, и передавать авторизацию в заголовке.

1. Полностью загружать дорожку в память, после чего добавлять ссылку к тегу audio используя `URL.createObjectURL` или MediaSource - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaSource
2. Использовать потоковое чтение с сервера + MediaSource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: Да безусловно эти варианты будут работать, но первый вариант потребует доработки на сервере(чего бы не хотелось), второй считаю небезопасным(мое мнение), с остальными не получается разобраться, но думаю они самые оптимальные, все таки еси существует механизм в HTML (раз есть атрибут crossorigin="use-credentials") хотелось бы использовать его, как наименее трудоемкий)

Comment: По поводу 2-ого варианта, не вижу разницы между заголовком и параметром url.

По поводу crossorigin, касается только cookies.
Можете хранить куку с токеном авторизации, и на сервере извлекать её.

Comment: По поводу второго варианта, в документации: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin написано, что crossorigin касается не только cookie(насколько я понял), а или cookie или Http аутентификация.  Поэтому и пытаюсь разобраться есть ли вообще такой способ. Считаю передачу токена в заголовке Authorization (а именно этот способ по моемку мнению и является стандартным методом http authorization) более безопасным чем передачу токена в query параметре get. Да и серверную часть не нужно будет трогать)